Why is the number of accessible microstates obtained by summing over each microstate?
I am studying statistical mechanics, and I am trying to understand an example used in my lectures to explain the canonical ensemble.
The example involves a system ($S$), submerged in a heat bath ($B$).
Temperature ($T$), Volume ($V$), and particle number ($N$) are kept constant. But crucially, the system is allowed to exchange energy with the heat bath, without changing the temperature $T$. (The energy of $S$ is negligible compared to $B$).

The total energy of the combined system is: $E_0 = E_B + E_S$
And the energy of each microstate of the system is denoted by $E_r$
Now I understand that number of accesible microstates for the bath for a certain $E_r$ is given by:
$$\Omega_B(E_0-E_r)$$
But I do not understand why the total number of microstaes accesible by the bath and the system is given by:
$$\sum_{r}^{}\Omega_B(E_0-E_r)$$
To me it seems that this equation should only produce states accessible by the heat bath for all energies of the system, and that it shouldn't include microstates accessible by the system.

It's because the constraints do not constrain the system's energy, only the total energy of system and bath. Therefore the pair can be in any of the following cases:
system in state 1, bath in any of $\Omega_B(E_0-E_1)$ states;
total = $1 \times \Omega_B(E_0-E_1)$
system in state 2, bath in any of $\Omega_B(E_0-E_2)$ states;
total = $1 \times \Omega_B(E_0-E_2)$
system in state 3, bath in any of $\Omega_B(E_0-E_3)$ states;
total = $1 \times \Omega_B(E_0-E_3)$
etc.
So the total number of states accessible to the combination (system plus bath) is
$$
\sum_r \Omega_B(E_0-E_r)
$$
In this formulation note that $r$ is counting individual microstates of the system (and not, for example, the system's energy levels), so there is just one system state for each value of $r$.

Ahhh, thank you for explicitly writing out the summations, this made it much easier for me to see why the states of the system are counted

One quick question: Why is the the probability of finding the system in state $r$, given by $\frac{\Omega_B(E_0-E_r)}{\sum_{r}^{}\Omega_B(E_0-E_r)}$, instead of $\frac{E_{r}}{\sum_{r}^{}E_r}$? I do not see how the two are equivalent.

The probability comes from a basic assumption, namely that all the accessible microstates of the total (i.e. isolated) system are equally likely. (That assumption can be justified by dynamic arguments, but I won't get into that). So to get the probabilities one should count the microstates, not their energies.
